# Is it possible to extend Evernote functionality?

Tags: evernote

I am interested in extending the functionality of Evernote, within the Evernote app on a Mac - much in the same way you add a macro in a spreadsheet to perform an automated function each time it is triggered.

I know it is possible to write other apps that can interact with Evernote via the API, but is it possible to create functionality within Evernote - add an icon, or a menu item, or a keyboard shortcut to fetch some live info from a web service, and paste it into the open doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, I managed to confirm that this sort of level of customization isn't available in the Evernote app itself, but found a very suitable way to accomplish this with another strategy: http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/40709-is-it-possible-to-extend-evernote-functionality-in-the-mac-app